# ContentResult directive or assembly missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
            var resultData = new { d = sqlObject.ToArray() };
            ContentResult result = new ContentResult();
            result.Content = serializer.Serialize(resultData);
            result.ContentType = "application/json";
            return result;
```

But they keep prompting that the type or the namespace name cannot be found. Are you missing an directive or assembly.

Are there any solutions to do?
I am developing on asp.net

Comment: Is this an ASP.Net MVC web project or ASP.Net web project? MVC will not work in an asp.net project type.

Answer (score 0):

install `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` package in your project from NuGet Package Manager.